# Django: Toggle active users

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

here in this project, i want to show the active bar when admin is logged in and show blue color and when any other user is logged in, i want to show the active bar on it and others on red color when the users are not active.
This is my html

```
<div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
            <table class="table table-hover text-nowrap" id="rooms">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>SN</th>
                  <th>Users</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {% for user in object_list %}
                <tr>
                  <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                  <td>{{user.username }}</td>
                  <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                  <td>
                   <label class="switch">
                      <input type="checkbox">
                      <span class="slider round"></span>
                    </label>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <span ><a class="btn btn-info mr-2" href="{% url 'dashboard:passwordreset'  %}"
                          ><i
                            class="fa fa-edit m-1"
                            aria-hidden="true"
                          ></i>Reset Password</a
                      ></span>
                  </td> 
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
            </table>
            
            </div>
          </div>
```

[Here I want to show green when admin is logged in and other active when other user is logged in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPYHU.png)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what do you mean : active or inactive user. But there is authenticated user, or anonymous user in django. So you can do this:

```
    {% if user.isauthenticated %} your css red or blue {% endif %}
```

Comment: When admin is logged in then, admin toggle should be green and other users toggle should be in red.

Comment: you can check if user is superuser with flag, {% if user.is_superuser %} you green css {% endif %}